# ios memory leak when accessing phone book

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, abaddressbook

[image: screen]

```
- (NSArray *)getAllContacts{

    CFErrorRef *error = nil;


    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted == YES) {

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Fetching contact info ----> ");
#endif


        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];


        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {
            ContactsData *contacts = [ContactsData new];

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get First Name and Last Name

            contacts.firstNames = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            contacts.lastNames =  (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (!contacts.firstNames) {
                contacts.firstNames = @"";
            }
            if (!contacts.lastNames) {
                contacts.lastNames = @"";
            }

            // get contacts picture, if pic doesn't exists, show standart one

            //            NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
            //            contacts.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            //            if (!contacts.image) {
            //                contacts.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NOIMG.png"];
            //            }
            //            //get Phone Numbers
            //
            //            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            //
            //            ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            //            for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {
            //
            //                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
            //                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
            //                [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
            //
            //                //NSLog(@"All numbers %@", phoneNumbers);
            //
            //            }


            //            [contacts setNumbers:phoneNumbers];

            //get Contact email

            NSMutableArray *contactEmails = [NSMutableArray new];
            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); i++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, i);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [contactEmails addObject:contactEmail];
                // NSLog(@"All emails are:%@", contactEmails);

            }

            [contacts setEmails:contactEmails];


            //---- if no mail id found then dont add contact
            if (contactEmails && contactEmails.count != 0) {
                [items addObject:contacts];
            }


#ifdef DEBUG
            //            NSLog(@"Person is: %@ # %@", contacts.firstNames,contacts.lastNames);
            //            NSLog(@"Phones are: %@", contacts.numbers);
            //            NSLog(@"Email is:%@", contacts.emails);
#endif




        }
        return items;



    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
#endif
        return nil;


    }

}
```

crash log:
Aug  6 19:11:08 IPad  : Fetching contact info ---->

Aug  6 19:11:08 IPad  : (Warn ) [ABLog]:  Actual default source doesn't exist

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : Got a 'k' packet, killing the inferior process.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : Sending ptrace PT_KILL to terminate inferior process.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : 38 +82.923904 sec [01c1/060b]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x01c2, tid = 0x2603, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : 39 +0.005248 sec [01c1/060b]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1c0b, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x27d93d48, task_info_outCnt => 8 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLGcI.png) (UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50][450]) : (UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50]) Exited: Killed: 9

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : Waited 20 ms for process to be reaped (state = Exited)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : 40 +0.025414 sec [01c1/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x4089ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] : Exiting.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad backboardd[28] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

--
thanks in advance

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how to resolve this memory leak problem ?

Comment: So please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace **__bridge** with **__bridge_transfer**

```
contacts.firstNames = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Referring to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

**__bridge** or **CFRelease** transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.

**__bridge_transfer** or **CFBridgingRelease** moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.
ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

Comment: exact answer without any here you can find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162306/crashing-application-when-accessing-phonebook-ios/25162462#25162462 
exact code is available here 
http://gauravds.blogspot.in/2014/08/get-address-book-or-phone-book-from-ios7.html