# crashing application when accessing phonebook ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, crash-reports, abaddressbook

[ios memory leak when accessing phone book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159379/ios-memory-leak-when-accessing-phone-book?noredirect=1#comment39169498_25159379) here is my orignal question and this is crash log. Memory leak problem has been resolved but application is crash when I access the contact and pop to navigation controller again push and accessing the contact, repeating this process 3-4 time and app will crash.

**crash log:**

```
Aug  6 19:11:08 IPad  <Warning>: Fetching contact info ----> 

Aug  6 19:11:08 IPad  <Notice>: (Warn ) [ABLog]: <ABSource.c ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource:111> Actual default source doesn't exist

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: Got a 'k' packet, killing the inferior process.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: Sending ptrace PT_KILL to terminate inferior process.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: 38 +82.923904 sec [01c1/060b]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x01c2, tid = 0x2603, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: 39 +0.005248 sec [01c1/060b]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1c0b, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x27d93d48, task_info_outCnt => 8 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50][450]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50]) Exited: Killed: 9

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: Waited 20 ms for process to be reaped (state = Exited)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: 40 +0.025414 sec [01c1/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x4089ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad com.apple.debugserver-310.2[449] <Warning>: Exiting.

Aug  6 19:11:57 IPad backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.baltech.gaurav[0x7f50]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

**It is my updated code**

```
- (NSArray *)getAllContacts{

    CFErrorRef *error = nil;


    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Fetching contact info ----> ");
#endif


        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];


        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {
            ContactsData *contacts = [ContactsData new];

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get First Name and Last Name

            contacts.firstNames = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            contacts.lastNames =  (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (!contacts.firstNames) {
                contacts.firstNames = @"";
            }
            if (!contacts.lastNames) {
                contacts.lastNames = @"";
            }

            // get contacts picture, if pic doesn't exists, show standart one

            //            NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
            //            contacts.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            //            if (!contacts.image) {
            //                contacts.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NOIMG.png"];
            //            }
            //            //get Phone Numbers
            //
            //            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            //
            //            ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            //            for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {
            //
            //                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
            //                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
            //                [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
            //
            //                //NSLog(@"All numbers %@", phoneNumbers);
            //
            //            }


            //            [contacts setNumbers:phoneNumbers];

            //get Contact email

            NSMutableArray *contactEmails = [NSMutableArray new];
            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); i++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, i);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [contactEmails addObject:contactEmail];
                // NSLog(@"All emails are:%@", contactEmails);


            }
            CFBridgingRelease(multiEmails);
            [contacts setEmails:contactEmails];





            //---- if no mail id found then dont add contact
            if (contactEmails && contactEmails.count != 0) {
                [items addObject:contacts];
            }


#ifdef DEBUG
            //            NSLog(@"Person is: %@ # %@", contacts.firstNames,contacts.lastNames);
            //            NSLog(@"Phones are: %@", contacts.numbers);
            //            NSLog(@"Email is:%@", contacts.emails);
#endif




        }
        CFBridgingRelease(addressBook);
        CFBridgingRelease(allPeople);
        CFBridgingRelease(source);

        return items;



    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
#endif
        return nil;


    }

}
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong *array count* value.  Try:

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);
```

BTW I've seen this code before with the same error.  Where did you get it?